# flex datagrid checkbox renderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, flex3

im my flex application i have a datgrid
as follows

```
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" > 
<mx:columns> 
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select"  dataField="itemSelInd" editable="false" textAlign="center"   >
                                <mx:itemRenderer >
                                    <mx:Component>
                                    <mx:CheckBox> 
                                </mx:CheckBox>
                                    </mx:Component>
                                </mx:itemRenderer>
                            </mx:DataGridColumn>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/> 
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="date" headerText="Date"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="month" headerText="Month"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="year" headerText="Year"/>


 </mx:columns> </mx:DataGrid>
```

by default editable = false;

now if i select a checkbox the corressponding row alone should become editable how its possible??
give me some suggestions..thankxx in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   <mx:ArrayCollection id="sad">
<mx:source>
    <mx:Object itemSelInd="true" named="sudharsanan" date="0" month="4" year="1989"/>
    <mx:Object itemSelInd="false" named="sudharsanan" date="1" month="4" year="1989"/>
    <mx:Object itemSelInd="true" named="sudharsanan" date="0" month="4" year="1989"/>
</mx:source>
</mx:ArrayCollection>
    <mx:DataGrid id="asad" editable="true" dataProvider="{sad}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select"  dataField="itemSelInd" editable="false" textAlign="center"   >
                                        <mx:itemRenderer >
                                            <mx:Component>
                                                <mx:CheckBox click="{data.itemSelInd = !data.itemSelInd}"/>
                                            </mx:Component>
                                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="named" headerText="Name" >
                <mx:itemEditor>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:TextInput editable="{data.itemSelInd}" text="{data.named}"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemEditor>
            </mx:DataGridColumn> 
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="date" headerText="Date" >
                <mx:itemEditor>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:TextInput editable="{data.itemSelInd}" text="{data.date}"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemEditor>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>

        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

I hope this might help you

Comment: This will only work if the property `data.itemSelInd` is bindable.

Comment: Could someone - be it Loremlpsum or somebody else - elaborate on what Loremlpsum is saying?  This may be related to an issue I'm having.  Thanks!

Comment: Basically in my own datagrid with the same approach, I'm seeing issues where the checkboxes that are checked are changing erroneously, at least if the number of elements is big enough (say, roughly twice the size that'll fit in the grid's visible range itself).  The erroneous modifications tend to happen a lot more when the user is scrolling.  Does this sound like a familiar error to anyone?